# How to not add same song to listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-os

If the user adds an individual song to the listbox and then adds a folder of songs including that song, how can I stop the program from adding the same song again because if it does it shows the full path to the song.
Also the same in reverse so if I add a folder of songs to the listbox and then add an individual song to it how can I stop the user from adding that same song to the listbox?

```
def browse_file():
    player.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a song",filetypes = (("MP3 files","*.mp3"),("WAV files","*.wav*"), ("all files","*.*")))
    playlist.append(player.filename)

    for t in playlist:
        listbox.insert(0, os.path.basename(t))




def select_dir():
    directory = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(directory)
    for files in os.listdir(directory):
        if files.endswith("mp3" or "wav"):
            playlist.append(files)

    for t in playlist:
        listbox.insert(0, t)
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/Hj44yGS3

Comment: You should store all songs (full path) in a list so you can check for duplicates. The listbox just displays the base filename from the file list.

Answer (score 0):

You should store all songs names with full their full paths included in an array so you can check for duplicates. The listbox just displays the base filename from the file list.